# Proceed to checkout button missing from cart Page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, extensions

The proceed to checkout button displays on the cart page when using the native OnePage checkout of magento (1.9.2.4). However, as soon as TM's Firecheckout module is used, the Proceed to Checkout button disappears. Important thing to note here is, that FIrecheckout is still accessible using the

> www.example.com/index.php/firecheckout/

But the button "Proceed to Checkout" is not displayed on the following page :

> www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

I have tried enabling as well as disabling the native onepage checkout module, but it doesn't make any difference. As soon as I disable the Firecheckout module, the "Proceed to checkout" button returns.

Has anyone ever faced this issue, or can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after about a few hours of debugging, I found the culprit. There was another module "Clarion_OnestepCheckout" which was disabled from the

> /var/www/vhosts/www.website.com/htdocs/app/etc/modules

and so, wasn't showing on the admin panel. I enabled it from the clarion_OnestepCheckout.xml file from the aforementioned path, and after the cache clearing, I saw TWO "proceed to checkout" buttons, not just one, both working for TM's Firecheckout module. Now, when I disabled it again from the clarion_onestepCheckout.xml file, finally there is just one "proceed to checkout" button, and so the problem resolved. 
The bottom line is, I believe there is some dependency issue that caused a conflict between the two checkout methods, resulting in random disappearance, and then dual reappearance of the checkout buttons.